# How to get the number of website or web pages competing for a specific keyword phrase?

Tags: google, keywords

How to get the number of website or webpages competing for a specific keywords phrase?

I know one would be going to Google and checking one by one manually.

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to get that figure as "competing" is a subjective term. A web page may rank well for a certain term but not be targeting it. Also, there may be pages that are targeting a phrase but don't rank well for it because of bad SEO/poor content.

If you're looking for an overall idea of how competitive a search phrase is, use [Google's Adwords Keyword Tool](https://adwords.google.com/o/Targeting/Explorer?__u=1000000000&__c=1000000000&ideaRequestType=KEYWORD_IDEAS#search.none) to get estimates from Google.

Comment: in my personal experience, Google Adwords is not accurate at all, particularly for phrases.

Answer (score 0):

There is another application

http://www.keycompete.com